# How do you change the default action of a hashed link to go to a different ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, hyperlink, anchor

I have a weird question, but hopefully you folks have an answer - as you often do.

We have some published links that go to our contact form: .../#ContactForm
We use the hashed link to go directly to the contact form at the bottom of our page.

However, I've made some edits and now want all the existing links to actually go to .../#InfoAboveContactForm, which is incidentally above the original. When people click the old .../#ContactForm link, they can't see the content in #InfoAboveContactForm.

...

```
<div id="InfoAboveContactForm">Some NEW information I want people to see</div>
<div id="ContactForm">Original Form fields are in here</div>
```

...

Is there anyway using jQuery or javascript to change the behavior of a hashed link to go to a different ID than designated in the window.location.hash?

```
<a href=".../#ContactForm">Go to the new #InfoAboveContactForm, not the original #ContactForm</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `.../#ContactForm` the exact URL you need to replace? Are you able to edit the HTML? Is there more than 1 link that needs to be replaced?

Comment: The exact URL looks more like {code}https://ourwebsite.com/#ContactForm{code}. That link has been already published in many other places, and would be extremely inconvenient to have to find and then change all the places where the original link has been published (fliers, websites, social media, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing some logic for the ready event, checking if the location hash was #ContactForm, and if it was, I would manipulate the window.location property to go to where I wanted it.